# ¿Cómo ocultar datos de una URL en C# al momento de usar ROTATIVA?

Tags: c#, mvc, rotativa

Estimadxs, vengo con una consulta ya que me ha vuelto un poco loco y es que no se como afrontarlo. Tengo un Html que tiene un form al cual redirigo para crear un PDF, el html hago esto:

```
        <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("CuotaInfo", "Detalle")">
            <div class="table-responsive border" style="width:95%; margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 7px;">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        @if (@Model.Count() == 1)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Suscriptor)</b></td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuota)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vencimiento)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "CuotaInfo", new { titulo = Html.Encode(item.Titulo), cuota = item.Cuota }, htmlAttributes: new { @target = "_blank" })</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Suscriptor)</b></td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuota)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vencimiento)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "CuotaInfo", new { titulo = item.Titulo, cuota = item.Cuota }, htmlAttributes: new { @target = "_blank" })</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

En mi Controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
    public ActionResult CuotaInfo(double? titulo, int? cuota)
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        var filtroSQL = conexionSQL.cargarDatos(titulo, cuota);

        int mesActual = DateTime.Now.Month;
        int anoActual = DateTime.Now.Year;
        try
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + titulo + "-" + cuota + ".pdf\"");

            if (filtroSQL[0].mesVigencia == mesActual && filtroSQL[0].anoVigencia == anoActual && cuota == 1)
            {
                return RotativaConfig("CuotaInfo", titulo, cuota);
            }
            else
            {
                if (filtroSQL[0].TipoCuota == "A")
                {
                    return RotativaConfig("CuotaA", titulo, cuota);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RotativaConfig("CuotaR", titulo, cuota);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private PartialViewAsPdf RotativaConfig(string htmlNombre, double? titulo, int? cuota)
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();

        return new PartialViewAsPdf(htmlNombre, conexionSQL.cargarDatos(titulo, cuota))
        {
            RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions
            {
                PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            }
        };
    }
```

Cuando se abre el html del pdf la url se ve así:

```
https://localhost:44312/Home/CuotaInfo?titulo=110538&cuota=5
```

Y yo quiero que se vea así:

```
https://localhost:44312/Home/CuotaInfo
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir esto?

Comment: tal vez por qué en tu return, le estas pasando el titulo y la cuota... yo también he usado rotativa pero algo más "sencillo" `return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Print");`, para que me devuelva la vista en pdf y ya por medio de `viewbag` les paso la info

Comment: Que versión de ASP, .net y Rotativa estas usando ?? Porque yo acabo de probar tu código (eliminando ciertas cosas que no están en .net 7 como `Response.AppendHeader`) y me funciona tal cual tu quieres

Comment: Versión de `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` y `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.es 5.2.9`, `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor` y `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.es 3.2.9`, `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` y `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.es 1.1.3`, `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` y `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.9` 
`ROTATIVA 1.7.3`, `Rotativa.Core 2.0.2.1` y `Rotativa.MVC 2.0.3` @Yussef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1.- Desde el Cliente

Lo más simple es hacerlo desde el cliente. Tu estas `Html.ActionLink` para crear unos enlaces que llaman al PDF, esto se hace por `GET`, si usaras `POST` no tendrías ese problema, para ello hay que colocar un formulario por fila, además de sacar el formulario padre que tienes ahora, que por lo visto no tiene utilidad alguna

```
<div class="table-responsive border" style="width:95%; margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 7px;">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
             
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Suscriptor)</b></td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuota)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vencimiento)</td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("CuotaInfo", "Detalle")" target="_blank">
                            <input type="hidden" name="titulo" value="@Html.Encode(item.Titulo)" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="cuota" value="@item.Cuota" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Detalle" />
                        </form>
                            
                </tr>
            }
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Otra opción similar seria crear el `form` dinamicamente con javascript

```
<div class="table-responsive border" style="width:95%; margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 7px;">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Suscriptor)</b></td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuota)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vencimiento)</td>
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="verPdf(@Html.Encode(item.Titulo),@item.Cuota)">Detalle</a></td>
                </tr>
            }

        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
function verPdf(titulo,cuota) {
    let form = document.createElement("form");
    form.style = "display:none";
    form.target = "_blank";
    form.method = "post";
    form.action = "@Url.Action("CuotaInfo")";

    let t = document.createElement("input");
    t.name = "titulo";
    t.value = titulo;

    let c = document.createElement("input");
    c.name = "cuota";
    c.value = cuota;

    form.appendChild(t);
    form.appendChild(c);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    form.remove();
}
</script>
```

### 2.- Desde el servidor

Desconozco si existe alguna magia arcana que permite cambiar la URL desde el servidor. Pero puedes generar una redirección a otro `Action` usando `RedirectToAction` el punto es que no deberás pasar los parámetros, ya que de hacerlo vuelves al mismo problema.

Entonces el truco está en pasar los parámetros por fuera, para esto puedes usar `TempData`

Que en la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd470171(v=vs.100)) pone:

*(traducción automática)*

> Puede utilizar un objeto TempDataDictionary para pasar datos del mismo
> modo que utiliza un objeto ViewDataDictionary. Sin embargo, los datos
> de un objeto TempDataDictionary sólo persisten de una solicitud a la
> siguiente, a menos que marque una o más claves para su retención
> mediante el método Keep. Si una clave está marcada para retención, la
> clave se conserva para la siguiente solicitud.
>
> Un uso típico de un objeto TempDataDictionary es pasar datos de un
> método de acción cuando redirige a otro método de acción. Por ejemplo,
> un método action puede almacenar información sobre un error en la
> propiedad TempData del controlador (que devuelve un objeto
> TempDataDictionary) antes de llamar al método RedirectToAction. El
> siguiente método de acción puede controlar el error y representar una
> vista que muestre un mensaje de error.

Donde habla del uso típico es justamente para lo que lo vamos a usar

```
public ActionResult CuotaInfo(double? titulo, int? cuota)
{
    TempData["titulo"] = titulo;
    TempData["cuota"] = cuota;

    ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
    var filtroSQL = conexionSQL.cargarDatos(titulo, cuota);

    int mesActual = DateTime.Now.Month;
    int anoActual = DateTime.Now.Year;
 

    if (filtroSQL[0].mesVigencia == mesActual && filtroSQL[0].anoVigencia == anoActual && cuota == 1)
    {
        TempData["htmlNombre"] = "CuotaInfo";
    }
    else if (filtroSQL[0].TipoCuota == "A")
    {
        TempData["htmlNombre"] = "CuotaA";
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["htmlNombre"] = "CuotaR";
    }
    return RedirectToAction("RotativaConfig");
}

// v--- lo hacemos public
public PartialViewAsPdf RotativaConfig()
{
    string htmlNombre = TempData["htmlNombre"].ToString();
    double? titulo = (double?)TempData["titulo"];
    double? cuota = (double?)TempData["cuota"];

    ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + titulo + "-" + cuota + ".pdf\"");
    return new PartialViewAsPdf(htmlNombre, conexionSQL.cargarDatos(titulo, cuota))
    {
        RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions
        {
            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Mañana a primera hora, lo pruebo y te comento que tal. Gracias!

Comment: Desde el cliente, la primer opción no me funcionó. La segunda opción funcionó de maravilla,. Desde el servidor, funcionó y me fascinó así que opté por dejarla ahí. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

public class MiControlador : Controller
{
public ActionResult MiAccion(int id)
{
// ... lógica de la acción ...

```
    var parametros = new RouteValueDictionary();
    parametros.Add("otro_parametro", "valor");

    // Renderizar la vista y generar el PDF
    var vistaHtml = new ViewAsPdf("MiVista", parametros)
    {
        FileName = "MiArchivo.pdf",
        PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4
    };

    return vistaHtml;
}
```

}

Comment: Necesitaría un poco más de explicación, porque tu ejemplo está bueno pero no se adapta a mi modelo. Gracias!

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Primero, modifica tu archivo HTML para incluir un formulario con el método POST y un botón de envío:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("CuotaInfo", "Detalle")">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="titulo" value="@item.Titulo" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cuota" value="@item.Cuota" />
    <button type="submit">Detalle</button>
    ...
</form>
```

Luego, en el controlador, asegúrate de agregar la anotación [HttpPost] sobre el método CuotaInfo y cambiar los parámetros para recibir un objeto del modelo en lugar de los valores individuales:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CuotaInfo(double titulo, int cuota)
{
    ...
}
```

El método RotativaConfig debe modificarse para recibir un objeto del modelo en lugar de los valores individuales:

```
private PartialViewAsPdf RotativaConfig(string htmlNombre, double titulo, int cuota)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT, ¿eres tú?

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.